# syntax error, unexpected end of file laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Bueno mi consulta es porque ya lei mil veces mi codigo y no encuento donde esta el error, tengo una app en php puro que estoy intentando integrar con laravel pero no encuentro el error del `syntax error, unexpected end of file`

cree el modelo, la vista y el controlador, hasta ahi todo bien pero al reflejar los datos mediante un SENDER, me arroja el error, ya lei el codigo y no encuentro donde esta el error:

```
 @section('titulo')
<h1>Crear Firma</h1>
@endsection

@section('content')
@if (Auth::check())
   @if(Auth::user()->firmas == 1)
   @if(!empty($_REQUEST['Sender'])):
    $sender = $_REQUEST['Sender'];
    $layout = file_get_contents('$datos->plantilla', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);

    @foreach ($sender as $key => $value) {
        $key         = strtoupper($key);
        $start_if    = strpos($layout, '[[IF-' . $key . ']]');
        $end_if      = strpos($layout, '[[ENDIF-' . $key . ']]');
        $length      = strlen('[[ENDIF-' . $key . ']]');

        @if (!empty($value)) {
            // Add the value at its proper location.
            $layout = str_replace('[[IF-' . $key . ']]', '', $layout);
            $layout = str_replace('[[ENDIF-' . $key . ']]', '', $layout);
            $layout = str_replace('[[' . $key . ']]', $value, $layout);
        } @elseif (is_numeric($start_if)) {
            // Remove the placeholder and brackets if there is an if-statement but no value.
            $layout = str_replace(substr($layout, $start_if, $end_if - $start_if + $length), '', $layout);
        } @else {
            // Remove the placeholder if there is no value.
            $layout = str_replace('[[' . $key . ']]', '', $layout);
        }
    }

    // Clean up any leftover placeholders. This is useful for booleans,
    // which are not submitted if left unchecked.
    $layout = preg_replace("/\[\[IF-(.*?)\]\]([\s\S]*?)\[\[ENDIF-(.*?)\]\]/u", "", $layout);

    @if (!empty($_REQUEST['download'])) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: text/html');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=efirma.html');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
    }
    @if (!empty($_REQUEST['Guardar'])) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: text/html');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=efirma.html');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
    }
    echo $layout;
@else: }}
                        <form name="formulario" role="form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" target="preview" id="form">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="nombre_cliente" class="col-md-1 control-label">Nombre</label>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="nombre_cliente" name="Sender[nombre]" placeholder="Selecciona un empleado" required>
                      <input id="id_cliente" type='hidden'>
                    </div>
                        <label for="Puesto" class="col-md-1 control-label">Puesto</label>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="puesto" class="form-control" id="puesto" name="Sender[puesto]" placeholder="Gerente administrativo"  readonly>
                    </div>
                        <label for="Email" class="col-md-1 control-label">Correo</label>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email_cliente" name="Sender[correo]" placeholder="Ingresa tu Email" readonly>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="Telefono" class="col-md-1 control-label">Telefono</label>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="telefono" class="form-control" id="telefono" name="Sender[telefono]" placeholder="+XX (XXX) XXX-XXXX" readonly="" value="{{ $datos->telefono_empleado }}">
                    </div>
                    <label for="Celular" class="col-md-1 control-label">Celular</label>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="celular" class="form-control" id="telefono_cliente" name="Sender[celular]" placeholder="+XX (XXX) XXX-XXXX" readonly>
                        </div>
                    <label for="Sitio" class="col-md-1 control-label">Sitio web</label>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="sitio" class="form-control" id="Sitio" name="Sender[sitio]" placeholder="www.ejemplo.com" value="{{ $datos->sitio_web }}" readonly>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="Direccion" class="col-md-1 control-label">Direccion</label>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="direccion" class="form-control" id="direccion" name="Sender[calle]" placeholder="Av. Paseo Centenario 303310" value="{{ $datos->direccion }}" readonly>
                    </div>
                        <label for="Colonia" class="col-md-1 control-label">Colonia</label>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="colonia" class="form-control" id="Colonia" name="Sender[colonia]" placeholder="Zona Urbana Rio" value="{{ $datos->colonia }}" readonly>
                        </div>
                        <label for="Ciudad" class="col-md-1 control-label">Ciudad</label>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="ciudad" class="form-control" id="Ciudad" name="Sender[ciudad]" placeholder="Tijuana, B.C." value="{{ $datos->ciudad }}" readonly>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="codigo" class="col-md-1 control-label">Codigo Postal</label>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="codigo" class="form-control" id="Codigo" name="Sender[codigo]" placeholder="22245" value="{{ $datos->codigo_postal }}" readonly>
                    </div>
                    <label for="facebook" class="col-md-1 control-label">Facebook</label>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="Facebook" name="Sender[facebook]"    value="{{ $datos->facebook }}"  readonly>
                    </div>
                    <label for="instagram" class="col-md-1 control-label">Instagram</label>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="Instagram" name="Sender[instagram]"  value="{{ $datos->instagram }}"  readonly>
                    </div>
                    <label for="twitter" class="col-md-1 control-label">Twitter</label>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="Twitter" name="Sender[twitter]"    value="{{ $datos->twitter }}"  readonly>
                    </div>
                    <label for="youtube" class="col-md-1 control-label">Youtube</label>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="Youtube" name="Sender[youtube]"    value="{{ $datos->youtube }}"  readonly>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="linkedin" class="col-md-1 control-label">Linkedin</label>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="Linkedin" name="Sender[linkedin]"    value="{{ $datos->Linkedin }}"  readonly>
                    </div>
                    <label for="google" class="col-md-1 control-label">Google+</label>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="Google" name="Sender[google]"   value="{{ $datos->google_plus }}"  readonly>
                    </div>
                    <label for="pinterest" class="col-md-1 control-label">Pinterest</label>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="Pinterest" name="Sender[pinterest]"    value="{{ $datos->pinterest }}"  readonly>
                    </div>
                    <label for="flickr" class="col-md-1 control-label">Flickr</label>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="Flickr" name="Sender[flickr]"    value="{{ $datos->flickr }}"  readonly>
                    </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <button id="preview" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="capturar()">
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> Ver Firma
                        </button>
                        <button id="download" class="btn btn-default" > Descargar Firma</button>
                        <input type="hidden" name="download" id="will-download" value="">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Catalogo de empleados
            </button>
                    </div>  
                </div>
                </form>
  </div>    
      <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="col-md-12">
@endif
                    @else
                    <h1>No tienes permisos para ver este modulo</h1>
                        <a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Comprar Modulo de firmas</a>
                    @endif

@endif
@endsection
```

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme porque esta volviéndome loco!
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no veo el @endforeach donde lo colocaste?

Comment: es que si lo coloco me arroja el error "syntax error, unexpected 'endforeach' (T_ENDFOREACH), expecting elseif (T_ELSEIF) or else (T_ELSE) or endif (T_ENDIF)"

Comment: sin embargo te comento que para cerrar el foreach debe ir el endforeach posterior se debe solucionar el otro error que mencionas, mismo que deberías mencionar en tu pregunta

Comment: también veo muchos if abiertos, seguro estas cerrando todos con un @endif?

Comment: Y, ¿a qué se debe que uses tanto `@`? ¿Sabes que usar eso en PHP es una pésima práctica de programación?

Comment: Yo soy muy nuevo en laravel, lo mio es php puro pero cuando mostre mi codigo a un compañero me dijo que php ya era obsoleto e inseguro, tengo poco con laravel y no entiendo su logica, este mismo codigo ejecutado en php puro funciona perfecto

Comment: tienes sectiones incluidas, pero no veo el extends del layouts

Comment: Si esta incluido, pero no lo puse porque esta hasta arriba, al momento no me ah dado ningun problema

Comment: ah vale @AbdielHernandez a seguir buscando

Comment: ¿Que PHP es obsoleto e inseguro? Pero si Laravel no es otra cosa que un framework (entre muchos otros) basado en PHP. Dile a tu compañero que no diga ese tipo de barbaridades. Lo que puede ser inseguro es la forma de programar, y eso te puede pasar en PHP puro, en Laravel o donde sea. Eso de creer que los framework hacen magia es falso, es más, a veces hasta te impiden aprender cómo funciona en sí el lenguaje. Yo programo en PHP puro y muy orgulloso de poder hacerlo.

Comment: y a mi tambien me gusta! solo quiero que antes de poder vender la app me asegure que sea segura, creo que lo mejor sera seguir estudiando laravel, este error me quebró la cabeza

Comment: @A.Cedano es que si usa la sintáxis de Blade en Laravel los condicionales y bucles van con @ por otro lado tu compañero Abdiel como dice que PHP es malo u obsoleto si Laravel lo que intentan usar no es mas que un Framework hecho en PHP

Comment: Gracias @AlfredoPaz no lo sabía, de hecho nunca he usado Laravel. Y no me parece justo que ellos decidan usar `@` para eso, sabiendo que `@` en PHP es para silenciar los errores.

Comment: te comento que al menos en experiencia propia cuando he usado condicionales y bucles en la sintáxis de Blade y cometo errores si me los muestra en el navegador; pero igual me documentaré al respecto pues no tenía presente ese detalle que comentas @A.Cedano gracias saludos

Answer (score 1):

Si revisas la [documentación de Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#if-statements), te darás cuenta que estás cometiendo algunos errores.

Para empezar si quieres [incluir php](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#php) en tu vista debes usar `@php` antes del bloque de código y cerrarlo con `@endphp`, por ejemplo en tu código deberías tener esto en una de tus líneas:

```
@php 
    $layout = preg_replace("/\[\[IF-(.*?)\]\]([\s\S]*?)\[\[ENDIF-(.*?)\]\]/u", "", $layout);
@endphp
```

TAmbién donde intentas hacer un `echo` puedes usar el bloque php, pero carecería de sentido, en lugar de ello puedes usar la consola de javascript o mostrar la data usando blade, que te provee [distintas opciones](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#displaying-data), entonces en lugar de tu `echo $layout;` podrías hacer algo así o en todo caso borrar esa línea:

```
{{ $layout }}
```

Otro pequeño detalle es que estás usando `:` después de un else, no se que intentas ahí pero es incorrecto (`@else:`), deberías borrarlo.

Ya en general la estructura de tu código como te mencionaban en los comentarios está mal escrita, revisa la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#if-statements) sobre condicionales y te darás cuenta que todo `@if` siempre se cierra con un `@endif` sin necesidad de usar llaves `{`,`}` y dentro puede contener cuantos `@else` y `@elseif` se desee. Lo mismo para los [bucles](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#loops) `@foreach`.

Bueno, intentando entender la estructura de tu código y quitando lo irrelevante te sugiero esta estructura, revisala y adáptala a tu código si es que no es la que quieres lograr.

```
@section('titulo')
<h1>Crear Firma</h1>
@endsection

@section('content')

@if (Auth::check())

   @if(Auth::user()->firmas == 1)
      @if(!empty($_REQUEST['Sender'])):

         // ...
         @foreach ($sender as $key => $value) 
           // ...
           @if (!empty($value)) 
               // ... 
           @elseif (is_numeric($start_if)) 
              // ... 
           @else 
              // ... 
           @endif
         @endforeach

         // Aquí usa @php
         @php 
            $layout = preg_replace("/\[\[IF-(.*?)\]\]([\s\S]*?)\[\[ENDIF-(.*?)\]\]/u", "", $layout);
         @endphp
         @if (!empty($_REQUEST['download'])) 
          // ...
         @endif
         @if (!empty($_REQUEST['Guardar'])) {
          // ...
         @endif

         echo $layout; <-- Borra esta linea o usa blade o la consola de tu navegador

      @else //aquí quita los dos puntos (:)        
         // ...

      @endif
   @endif

@else
    // ...
@endif

@endsection
```

Finalmente recomendarte usar tabulaciones y leer la documentación, la idea es que el framework te facilite el trabajo y lo hace, sólo hay que leer un poquito más. Saludos